# Access Google App Engine Hosted Site without using DNS

Tags: dns, google-app-engine

I have a site hosted at Google App Engine. Its current address is in the format like `xxx.appspot.com`. Now I want someone to have access to it by typing some IP along with sub-directory, like `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/dir1/dir2/dir3`. How can I do that?

Comment: Could you modify your question to include _why_ you want that kind of setup?

Comment: I would like to tell but the reason is very complicated.

Answer (score 1):

This would be near-impossible to accomplish. It is easy to [set up a GAE app on a custom domain](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain), but it seems the OP has some more specific requirements.

The `xxx.appspot.com` domain can certainly be translated to an IP address, but GAE's servers will not be able to respond to requests by IP address. It has to know which app you are trying to access, and cannot do so without seeing the hostname. Also, Google might change the IP address associated with your hostname at any time, so you cannot depend on it.

Additionally, making it respond to a sub-path is not easy. If it is at all possible, it would involve altering your app, so that it basically ignores requests to anything but the desired sub-path.

However, I suspect you want to do this because you want to run other (non-GAE?) services on the same IP (that you own), while having your GAE app "installed" on the specified path. This is generally not possible.
You might be able to work around it by setting up a web proxy on the desired path, which forwards all requests to the GAE app.

Comment: Ok, I have nothing much techy like you said in my fourth para. I was also hoping of it being nearly-impossible. Only I want is no DNS. I want site to available at any IP including google along with any how complicated directory structure.

Comment: Ok, I think should mention for that. I have seen many free proxy internet tricks like http://www.tipsplanet.in/2013/01/free-idea-3g-gprs-trick-2013.html that really works. These tricks requires only a host that is accessible by some IP. So, I was planning of installing a proxy script at GAE and try this trick on GAE.

Comment: Yes, proxying could work, but be prepared to do some configuration tweaking to get the sub-path part working.

Comment: GAE is definitelly best free proxy as it is fast, reliable and there is no risk of data mining.